# how to write "<" in HTML contained in a QString for a QTextEdit widget

Tags: c++, qt

i'm new in QT. i'm writting code for a " C++ class generator". I'm generating a QString from data introduced in a main window to put it in a QTextEdit widget in a second window. I'm using some of HTML code in my QString "Generated_code" . the matter is that when I introduce the "<" charctere it's concidered as an HTML tag so it's not shown in the resulted text. so how can I write this character and continue using HTML in my QString ( because there another solution concisting on writing the QString whithout using any HTML code)?

what I'm getting in the resulted text
... ....some text
include header1>
include header2>
... etc
. some other text

```
void MainWindow::OpenDialogWindow()
{
....some other code

// a part of where i'm actually constructing the QString (MainWindow class methode)
if(!m_headers->itemText(0).isEmpty())
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < m_headers->count() ; i++)
        {
            Generated_code += "<br>#include <><<>"  + m_headers->itemText(i) + "<>><></br>";
        }
    }
.
.
.
..... some other code
m_codeGenerated_Window = new CodeGeneratedWindow(Generated_code);
    m_codeGenerated_Window->exec();
}



// the constructor of the second window
CodeGeneratedWindow::CodeGeneratedWindow(QString text)
{
    m_diagLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    m_text = new QTextEdit();
    m_text->setText(text);;

.... some code 
}
```

Comment: Probably `&lt;` because that's how HTML works.

Comment: You can find escape sequences for markup on wikipeduia page. And yes, it's &lt; for <, &gt; for >.

Comment: yes ! it actually work with &lt;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < m_headers->count() ; i++)
{
    const auto cCode = QString("#include <%1>").arg(m_headers->itemText(i));
    Generated_code += QString("<br>%1</br>").arg(cCode.toHtmlEscaped());
}
```